# What are the differences in using malloc or not using it in this code?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

**As some have said, this block does not do as I thought. I was trying to allocate the memory block and then store the character string literal within it - but now after looking at it again it's obvious that is not what I have done here.**

What is the difference if you were to do this:

```
    char* memory = malloc(sizeof("String"));
    memory = "String"; //edit: memory leaked
    printf("%s", memory);
    free(memory); //edit
```

Or this:

```
    char* noMemory = "String";
    printf("%s", noMemory);
```

Comment: Your first example leaks memory and doesn't do what you think it does. The second should be a `const char *`, and most compilers will tell you this via warning or error. To just send the string "String" to stdout requires you allocate *no* additional memory. There is no simple answer to your closing question except to say "when you *need* it." (and in this case, *you don't*).

Comment: Well, assuming that I used free(memory) later on. What are the differences? And my compiler did not give any errors compiling this code.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to pick up a good book on C. StackOverflow is not meant to teach you programming through Q&A of this kind.

Comment: `free(memory)` later on in the first example will likely seg-fault your process. That isn't the leak problem. The leak is the immediate loss of the memory address you *just got* from the allocator on the first line by overwriting it with the string address assignment on the next. This isn't Java or C#. I suggest a strong read-up on pointers and memory allocation methods.

Comment: I changed the context of the question a bit. I meant for the question originally to be more on the difference between using malloc for the string or not using it and what are the differences between them - not a very general "when to use malloc" question.

Comment: @Mat, I thought that the line free(memory) would free the memory block associated with the pointer "memory.

Comment: @user4815162342, I did not intend for the question to be so broad. I just was curious regarding the difference of using malloc or not using it within the case. I have made changes to the OP accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but you made `memory` point to a static string literal, you've already leaked the stuff malloc returned.

Comment: Answering the title and question body as you now have it, the difference is this: The first one leaks memory and will probably seg-fault your process (technically the behavior of the potential seg-fault is **undefined**, but I would bet money on it). The second makes no dynamic allocation, and though the compiler will probably complain that you're assigning a `const char*` string literal address to a `char*` non-const pointer variable, it will run correctly if the compiler is lenient enough.

Comment: Here's a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600181/allocate-memory-and-save-string-in-c

Comment: @Mat, From what I have gathered across various sources, memory leaks are when you lose access to a particular block of memory by reassigning a pointer that was pointer to it. I was not aware there are other types of memory leaks. Any literature on this topic come to mind?

Comment: You described exactly what you're doing above :-) Look at the link I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: @WhozCraig Why should a variable that receives a `char *` (the question is tagged “C”) have to be `const char *`, and why should a compiler issue warning or error if it isn't?

Comment: @Mat, OHH - that is what WhozCraig was referring to in his originally statement. I see now .. I actually MEANT for the string to be stored within the block of memory. I see what I did now. Thanks!

Comment: @PascalCuoq because its a terrible idea to do otherwise. C does (agreed) decay a string literal address to a non-const pointer, but it doesn't do you any good because *modifying* the string literal underneath that pointer is undefined behavior. If your C-compiler is worth its salt (and your warnings are pedantic) it will flag this and you should heed that warning.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, WhosCraig was referring to the non-constant char pointer being assigned to the constant string literal. It's good programming practice since data that will never be changed is stored in a difference location than something that is dynamic.

Comment: @sherrellbc I think he knows that (in fact, I'm sure of it). It was the language difference he was bringing to question (C++ doesn't allow it at all; C still does, but there is no point to it doing so). I am, however, glad that *you* understood it.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I have always done so when working with other constants, but have not thought that constant string literals be treated similarly - nor have I ever had a compiler complain about it. Perhaps I should do a bit of research to make my compiler a bit more pedantic. At any rate, what are the technical terms for the memory space in which dynamic memory is allocated as opposed to constants?

Comment: Neither `clang -pedantic -Wall` nor `gcc -pedantic -Wall` warn for `char *p = "s";`. It seems the only C compiler worth its salt is a C++ compiler. Regarding the usefulness of not treating string literal as pointers to const char, there are those who say there is no legal way to sort `const char *` pointers with `qsort()` (I haven't made my opinion about this yet), so one use case would clearly be if you intend to sort your string literals.

Comment: @PascalCuoq sorting my string literals I would use a writable index-array of `const char*`; the array of pointers being writable, while the data *through* the pointers is obviously not. Not sure how you are invoking your `qsort()` nor on what container you're using it with. Regarding the compiler warnings, I can't explain why, but my LLVM compiler on my Apple MacBook Air whines when I enable pedantic and warnings-as-errors Perhaps it is as you say and my compile-as setting is switched to always-C++. I'll have to check that.

Comment: @sherrellbc would you mind reposting this question with your updated edits.  With all of the comments referring to the original version of your question it is hard to figure out your current question is.  Note, we are all learning, so don't feel bad about your question.  The problem of memory leaks being coded by experienced programmers essentially prompted microsoft to create *.NET!!!

Comment: @JackCColeman the question is now "What is  the difference between using the stack option for allocating the string or using malloc() to." It seems that both options are viable, but but malloc() has a lot of overhead associated with memory allocation and storage.

Comment: @sherrelbc, memory is divided between the stack and the heap.  So when you allocate a string available memory is still decreased by the length of the string.  The overhead of managing the stack versus the heap is either similar or the difference is not significant.  The issue with having a variable on the stack versus the heap is that of persistence.  If the variable is no longer needed when the routine ends then use the stack, if it needs to remain allocated for other routines, use the heap.  This is a very general statement and can be argued with but for starters its a good way to think.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular example, you are leaking memory and ending up with undefined behaviour for trying to free the constant string `"string"`, since you are first allocating `memory`, then assigning it with the address of `"string"`, so losing track of the original allocation.

You need to use `strcpy(memory, "String");` to copy the string.

Now, besides that, unless you are just doing that, you'd be wasting a lot of clock-cycles, because `malloc` and `free` are not free operations, they take time, and of course, copying the string will take some operations too. On top of that, the memory allocated with `malloc` will take up more space than the actual string, both because the `malloc` and `free` functions need a bit of information "next to" the memory block to be able to do their job, and because, typically, the size is rounded up to some "good" size, e.g. 8, 16 or 32 bytes. Which means that you are not just wasting clock-cycles calling malloc and free, but you are also using more memory than you actually asked for. So instead of using 7 bytes, you are perhaps using 40 or 64 bytes.

On the other hand, if you wanted to modify the string, then you can't just use the existing memory for `"String"`, since that is not guaranteed to be "writeable" memory, so again, you end up with `undefined behaviour` (that would probably mean a crash on any modern OS). There are however several other possible solutions for that, for example:

```
 char local[15] = "String";
```

will give you 15 bytes worth of space for a string on the stack - there is no overhead on the amount of space to talk of [up to 7 bytes at most], and we can ignore the overhead of allocating it on the stack, because it's a single instruction which has to be there if you use local variables at all - and it's one instruction for ALL local variables together.

This solution allows the string to be modified (e.g. `strcat(local, " abc");` to make `"string abc"`. Just make sure you know what you are doing, and don't overwrite the end of the allowed space [and don't forget to count the zero at the end of the string].

Comment: This is precisely what I was asking. So, without malloc() the string is allocated on the stack, and with it the string is, if strncpy() is used, alloacted in memory somewhere, right? I think I need to read more regarding the Stack and Heap. I have only a vague understanding of these concepts. All I know of the Stack is that it, at least in Java, function calls are placed on top of each other with all of their members (i.e. local variables) being allocated at the same time. Last on first off. That about sums up my understanding.

Comment: @sherrellbc In your second version, a *pointer* to the string is allocated on the stack.  The string literal itself is read-only and can be stored in the program's data segment, which is neither part of the stack nor the heap. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

Comment: @sherrellbc: In your second case, the string lives somewhere - the POINTER (which holds the location of the string itself) to it is allocated on the stack. If you use `char str[x] = "string";` then it is allocated on the stack. The stack is indeed where the function calls are on, but also where local variables are stored. So if you have a `int i;` inside a function, it will occupy an `int`-sized space on the stack.

Comment: It makes a lot more sense now. So the pointer to the string literal would be placed inside the main() function call on the stack it seems.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using a different word than jamesdlin, we mean the same thing. You have presented two pieces of code, which can be seen as two cases or two versions of how to do something.

Comment: I looked at it briefly and thought you had authored both comments - thus my confusion. Sorry for that moment of idiocy. It appears I have much more to learn on these topics. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The differences between these two version are as follows.

1. In the first version, you allocate memory, which you are leaking, because instead of using the returned memory, you are immediately overwriting it with a new value (the pointer to the statically allocated string).
2. Additionally you free the memory to the statically allocated string, because you already lost the pointer you allocated. This will lead to undefined behaviour.

The second version, on the other hand is (almost) ok. You should get a warning though, because the pointer should be 'const'.

If you want to assign the string to the allocated memory, you should either use `strcpy` or alternatively you could use `strdup`, in which case you don't need to `malloc` you still have to free it though. Another method would be to statically allocate an array for the string, since you already know the string.

**EDIT**

Regarding your comment in the other posting:

If you have a literal string, it will be stored in the BSS segment. So you can use it directly, without the need of allocating extra space for it. However, there is the limitation, that you shouldn't modify such a string, because this is undefined behaviour. The OS may choose to have such data in protected memory, which might cause your program to segfault, or it might work.

Comment: Point 3 is incorrect. `sizeof "literal"` accounts for the NUL-terminator.

Comment: I have realized at this point that there is a memory leak right off. I understand where I had made the mistake. But I know that sizeof("string") would actually return 8.

Comment: @jamesdlin, OK, I removed that. Is this defined in the standard? I never woul duse such an expresision though, even though I know that it is optimized to the same label anyway.

Comment: @Devolus A string literal `"abc"` is of type `char[4]`, so `sizeof` is guaranteed to return 4.  See section 6.4.5/5 of the ISO C99 standard.