# Allocating struct heap vs stack: Pthread_create

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am trying to allocate memory dynamically for the arg_struct. If I just allocate it on the stack it works correctly, but not dynamically. Dynamically it prints the string in the main function but when it is passed to the thread function it doesn't work. Any ideas as to why it doesn't work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


struct arg_struct {
    int *arg1;
    char *str;
};

void *print_the_arguments(void *arguments)
{
    struct arg_struct *args = (struct arg_struct *)arguments;
    printf("The result is : %s\n",args->str);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t some_thread;
    struct arg_struct *args = malloc(sizeof(struct arg_struct));
    //struct arg_struct args; // uncommenting this and args.str WORKS (prints to thread function)
    args->str = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    args->str = "hello";
    //args.str = "hello";
    printf("printing from main: %s\n", args->str); // Prints here but not in other function

    if (pthread_create(&some_thread, NULL, &print_the_arguments, (void *)&args) != 0) {
        printf("Uh-oh!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return pthread_join(some_thread, NULL); /* Wait until thread is finished */

}
```

Comment: This: `args->str = malloc(sizeof(char)*5); args->str = "hello";` allocates five bytes (when you seem to have wanted 6) and then just immediately loses that memory when you assign something else to `args->str`.

Comment: In the future, please remove those line numbers before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
29     if (pthread_create(&some_thread, NULL, &print_the_arguments, (void *)&args) != 0) {
```

should be

```
29     if (pthread_create(&some_thread, NULL, &print_the_arguments, (void *)args) != 0) {
```

when you are dynamically allocating args. Also, I'd advise

```
 25     args->str = strdup("hello");
```

and skip the `malloc`.

This code:

```
 24     args->str = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
 25     args->str = "hello";
```

results in a memory leak, the memory from malloc is leaked. Perhaps you meant

```
 24     args->str = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
 25     strcpy(args->str, "hello");
```

but that is also incorrect. The 5 should be a 6 to account for the null character
at the end of the string. `strdup()` is a good shortcut for `malloc` followed by `strcpy`.

Comment: +1, the cast to `void *`, the `&` in front of `print_the_arguments` and the `sizeof(char)` in the OP's code are also unnecessary.

Comment: Possibly not needed but, unnecessary? That code was from another stackoverflow page; I just altered it a little. Also, this  page has the cast to void*. https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ This site also uses sizeof(char): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600181/allocate-memory-and-save-string-in-c